# How to get path to flex element through a browser?

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, plugins, browser

Is there any plugin for any browser which can tell me the pass to certain flex element?

I mean, I have a flex frontend. And I need to find the full path to some element, like `/topLevelPanel/innerPanel/checkbox[0]/img`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear what you're asking for, but..

If the SWF is calling external elements, such as an image, you can probably find out which ones w/ a tool such as ServiceCapture or Charles.  They aren't quite browser plugins, though.

That said, in many cases, all Flex elements are compiled directly into the SWF.  There is no independent path available for these elements.